# I need to prove that the set of the solutions of the ODE $\dot{x} = Tx$ is a vector subspace of $C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation, $\mathbf{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the IVP

$$\begin{cases} 
\dot{\mathbf{x}} = T\mathbf{x} \\
\mathbf{x}(t_0) = \mathbf{x}_0
\end{cases}$$

has an unique solution in $\mathbb{R}$.

Using this theorem, i need to prove that the set of the solutions of the ODE $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = T\mathbf{x}$ is a vector subspace of the vector space $C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)$ with dimension = $n$.

I'm stucked in this problem since yesterday, and i still can't figure out how to show that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit:

I figured out (with the helps from the answers below) how to show that the space of the solutions is a vector subspace. However i still have doubts on how to prove its dimension. I didnt understand very well why should we do the steps that Samuel presented. So here are my new questions:

1- Why should i build $n$ IVPs to build a basis to the subspace? And why the initial conditions should be the elements of the standard basis of $R^n$?

2- How to prove that the answers to the IVPs are LI each other? I guess that taking a determinant of the answers could work, right?

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: The initial condition implies there is **only one** solution to this IVP. If you remove it then linearity implies that the sum of two solutions is a solution and any solution multiplied by a scalar is a solution too.

Comment: Hello Darweesh, thanks for the answer. I'm sorry, i forgot that the x0 is also a vector. Does this change your answer? I was thinking here and the unicity is due the theorem, right? And what you want to say with removing it? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution to the ODE will be a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (that is, an element of $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n))$, so in order to check that the set of solutions is a vector space you only have to show that the sum of solutions is a solution and the multiplication of a solution times scalar is a solution.

Let $x_1, x_2$ be solutions to the ODE, and let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ be a scalar. Then

1. If $z=x_1+x_2$, $$\dot{z}=\dot{x}_1+\dot{x}_2=Tx_1 + Tx_2 = T(x_1+x_2)=Tz$$
   so $z$ is a solution to the ODE.
2. If $w=\lambda x_1$,
   $$\dot{w}=\lambda\dot{x}_1=\lambda Tx_1 =T(\lambda x_1)= Tw$$
   so $w$ is a solution to the ODE.

Finally, since $\lambda$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ were arbitrary, we have proven that the set of solutions to the ODE is indeed a vector subspace of $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Now, to see that it has dimension $n$, let's construct a basis. Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be the *only* solutions that satisfy $x_i(t_0)=\operatorname{e}_i$ (the $i$-th vector of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$) for $i=1,\ldots,n$. As functions, they are linearly independent since their initial values are linearly independent. To conclude the proof, let's see that any solution to the ODE can be written as a linear combination of these $x_i$'s.

Let $y$ be a solution to the ODE, and let $v=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=y(t_0)$. Now, let $z=\sum_{i=1}^n v_ix_i$. Note that $z(t_0)=\sum_{i=1}^n v_ix_i(t_0)=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\operatorname{e}_i=y(t_0)$, so, by uniqueness of solutions, $y=z=\sum_{i=1}^n v_ix_i$. Hence $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is a basis of the space of solutions to the ODE and therefore it has dimension $n$.

Comment: Another way of viewing the proof that the dimension is $n$: use the unique existence of solutions to show that the linear transformation which sends a solution $\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{x}(t_0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is an isomorphism between the solution space and $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler, could you please give me a little hint of how it could be done? Just the key aspects. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Samuel, thanks a lot for the amazing answer. In fact i wasnt expecting more than intuitions to help me to find the right path, but i appreciate so much your effort, you made it very clear. 

Edit: 

I still cant figure out why should we do the strategy of create n IVPs. Could you explain this?

Comment: The key aspects are briefly: the existence of a solution for any initial condition vector $\mathbf{x}_0$ shows that the linear transformation I mentioned is surjective (onto), and the uniqueness of solutions shows that the linear transformation mentioned is injective (one-to-one).

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, @DanielSchepler. Let me ask one more thing: as i can see by your answer, i can show that any element of the Rn is sended (one-to-one) to an element of the subspace. So, this need to happen with the basis of Rn, wich will be sended to a basis of the subspace? Can i justify this using the argument: Since an element of Rn can be thinked as a v = sum from i to n = ai * ei. So Tv = sum from i to n ai*Tei. But Tei = wi, and necessarily wi is a basis of the output space?

Comment: Yes, a generalization of that argument shows that two isomorphic vector spaces always have equal dimensions (and that's a fact that usually can be used without needing to cite it, though perhaps not in an introductory linear algebra class which hasn't covered that fact yet).

Comment: @DanielSchepler. I asked a collegue about this intuition that i had after i saw your first answer and she warned me about that we're not dealing with vectors, but functions. But since i can write a function that outputs an Rn element as a "vector" in the form a(t) = a1(t)*e1 + a2(t)*e2 + ... an(t)*en, then it shoudnt be a problem, right? Am i wrong? Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: I'm not sure what you (or your colleague) mean: a function can absolutely also be a vector, and in fact there are many standard examples of vector spaces which consist of functions ($C^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^n)$ in this question being one of them).

Comment: @DanielSchepler, i'm also not sure what she mean to kkk.  I'm thinking in this problem as the functions being vectorial functions, so i have a function a(t) = a1(t)i + a2(t)j + a3(t)k as an R3 example. So my final answer might be: By the theorem, if we know an initial condition, we can affirm that there is a one-to-one correspondence of the elements of the input space and the output space. By this fact, we can say that the two spaces are isomorphous, and hence, the dimension of the output space should be the dimension of the input space: n.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I can reinforce this argument using the definition of the set, that if a(t) is a solution, so it should verify a'(t) = Ta(t). And since a(t) = sum ai*ei -> a'(t) = T(sum ai*ei) = (sum ai*Tei) = ai*wi. And since the isomorfism of the spaces, they need to have the same numbers of elements in their basis. Thank you so much for the discussion and for the help!